# Intel MPI Benchmarks result exceeds network bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, mpi, benchmarking

I was running the [Intel MPI Benchmarks](https://github.com/intel/mpi-benchmarks) on a mini MPI cluster of two nodes on AWS EC2.

The executables of the benchmark were compiled with `make CC=/usr/bin/mpicc CXX=/usr/bin/mpicxx`.

The cluster was set up based on [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster).
(What I did differently is that I installed OpenMPI instead of MPICH.)

The type of the AWS instances is t3a.xlarge.
According to [this spec](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) the network performance is up to 5 Gbps (i.e. **625 MB/s**).

I chose Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS for these instances.

The PingPong benchmark gave me surprising results:

```
mpiuser@mpin0:~$ mpirun -rf rankfile -np 2 ./IMB-MPI1 PingPong
#------------------------------------------------------------
#    Intel(R) MPI Benchmarks 2019 Update 3, MPI-1 part
#------------------------------------------------------------
# Date                  : Thu Nov 28 15:17:38 2019
# Machine               : x86_64
# System                : Linux
# Release               : 4.15.0-1054-aws
# Version               : #56-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 7 16:15:59 UTC 2019
# MPI Version           : 3.1
# MPI_Datatype          : MPI_BYTE


#---------------------------------------------------
# Benchmarking PingPong
# #processes = 2
#---------------------------------------------------
       #bytes #repetitions      t[usec]   Mbytes/sec
            0         1000        32.05         0.00
            1         1000        31.74         0.03
            2         1000        31.98         0.06
            4         1000        32.08         0.12
            8         1000        31.86         0.25
           16         1000        31.30         0.51
           32         1000        31.40         1.02
           64         1000        32.86         1.95
          128         1000        32.66         3.92
          256         1000        33.56         7.63
          512         1000        35.00        14.63
         1024         1000        34.74        29.48
         2048         1000        36.56        56.02
         4096         1000        39.80       102.91
         8192         1000        49.92       164.10
        16384         1000        57.73       283.79
        32768         1000        78.86       415.54
        65536          640       170.26       384.91
       131072          320       239.80       546.60
       262144          160       357.34       733.61
       524288           80       609.82       859.74
      1048576           40      1106.36       947.77
      2097152           20      2514.62       833.98
      4194304           10      5830.39       719.39
```

**Some of the speeds exceed 625 MB/s.**

The `rankfile` was used to force distributing the two processes onto two nodes.
It is not the case that the two MPI processes are running on the same node.
The content of the `rankfile` is:

```
rank 0=mpin0 slot=0
rank 1=mpin1 slot=0
```

What are the possible reasons that caused the benchmark result to exceed the theoretical limit?

Comment: Is that maybe measuring *aggregate* bandwidth, so multiple pairs of nodes communicating with each other can happen in parallel, each with 5Gb/s?  Or is that 5Gb/s just a guaranteed minimum?

Comment: In my case only two nodes are involved, and on each node there is only one MPI process.
5Gb/s is the guaranteed maximum according to AWS's spec.

Comment: It is not unusual to exceed the EC2 "up to" limits, especially for short periods of time, e.g. when there is unused capacity it is probably in Amazon's interest to let you use it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, Is there a way to set this limit? Since my experiment is to see how close to the theoretical bandwidth MPI's performance can be, it will lose the point if the upper limit is not fixed and unknown.

Comment: At the EC2 level I doubt it, but at the OS or TCP/IP level perhaps. Probably worth another question.